# user level threads kernel level threads and fibers

Tags: windows, multithreading, kernel

I know that fibers run within the context of a thread. They are user-level only.

I know threads can be user level or kernel level.

When you create a thread in a user-level application it is user-level also?

Can you create a kernel-level thread in your user application?

These user-level threads are also scheduled by the kernel?

When you call CreateThread in .NET how does the kernel come into play? Does the CreateThread function need to go through the susbsystem dll to the executive and all the way down to the kernel for creating a user-level thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Windows platform threads in user mode processes (applications) are user mode threads and threads in kernel mode processes are kernel mode threads.  You can not create a kernel mode thread in a user mode process.  On Windows all threads are scheduled by the kernel directly or indirectly (via how it configures CPU interrupts).

The .Net CreateThread ultimately uses the CreateThread API, which is exported from Kernel32.dll.

Comment: "On the Windows platform threads in user mode processes (applications) are user mode threads" -> No. User/kernel level threads does not mean at which level they are asked to be created. I means that at which level they are manged. If you build a thread in windows by comming languages (C# threading, C++ threads, Python threads, etc.) it is a kernel-level thread because the kernel is responsible for its scheduling. User level threads are usually managed and scheduled at user level and the kernel is NOT aware of their existence.

Comment: @Gupta How would you create a thread on the Windows platform without the kernel managing/scheduling it?

Comment: You should use a library that allows you to create a user-level thread. I am not aware of any on Windows. But, these libraries create user-level threads without the kernel to be notified. When a user-level thread wants to do a context switch, it is the responsibility of the library to do the switch, not the kernel.